# Xcode/iPhone -- break when the next event enters my code?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I am working on a large (>30k lines) event-driven app.  I have a sequence of inputs that produces a bug.  What I want to do is to break as soon as the final input enters my code.

Is there a general way to do that?

I understand that for any specific sequence of inputs, I can find out where that last input is going to enter my code, then set a breakpoint there.  What I would like to do is take out the step of "find out where that last input enters my code."  In other words, I am running the app in the simulator, and I want to set a flag somewhere that says "break the next time you are going to enter non-system Objective C code."  Then I send the event that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you are asking, but have you tried using an **Exception Breakpoint**? This will basically act like an auto-inserted breakpoint on the piece of code that throws the exception. If that doesn't work for you, try a symbolic breakpoint

Comment: Some bugs don't generate exceptions.  It could be an incorrect output, for example.

Comment: That's why I mentioned symbolic breakpoints. You can set the 'Symbol' to whatever you want (e.g. -[ClassWithInput methodTriggered]), and even set a condition, or an arbitrary amount of times to ignore this call. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html

Comment: +1 for symbolic breakpoints, that should really be the emphasis of your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to intercept UI events, you can try subclassing `UIWindow` and overriding its `sendEvent:` method, then setting this class as the class of the UIWindow object in your main XIB file. `sendEvent:` will be called each time the user generates a touch event. Unfortunately, at this point you cannot yet know which UI object will finally consume the event (read: which event handler code will be ultimately called) since that depends on the actual state of the responder chain. But anyway, you can use this method to inject events into the system.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But the event may then go through some system code before it reaches my code.  Stepping through that code may or may not be easy.